# Order by SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

This is product table structure for online portal.
Currently product table have more than 1 million records.

[image]

I created index on status & delivery id.
I having performance issue when list product by `ORDER BY status DESC, delivery_id ASC`
Full Query :

```
SELECT product_name FROM product ORDER BY status DESC, delivery_id ASC LIMIT 10
```

How to improve this query to perform faster?

Comment: please paste the explain plan

Comment: look at documentation for order by optimization http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [`ORDER BY` Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/order-by-optimization.html):

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the `ORDER BY`, although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the `WHERE` clause. These cases include the following:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - You mix `ASC` and `DESC`:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 ASC;
>   ```

Comment: Is the any solution for this?

Comment: @Basilevs: One option would be to define `status` or `delivery_id` differently, so that the desired ordering need not sort them in opposing directions.

Comment: Can we create reversed index without changing column definition?

Comment: @Basilevs: My proposal above would not affect the "column definition" (in terms of schema) - merely the semantic definition of its values.  As for creating a "*reversed index*", I'm not entirely sure what you mean: MySQL can traverse indexes in *either* direction, it just can't traverse one key part in one direction and another key part in the opposing direction.

Comment: @RajanRaj: I really would urge you to try the approach [I suggested above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355471/order-by-sql-query#comment19958483_14355568), if at all possible.

Comment: @eggyal, can you explain me which method I suppose to follow?

Comment: @RajanRaj: define `status` or `delivery_id` differently, so that the desired ordering need not sort them in opposing directions.

Comment: do you want create index on status & delivery_id separately?

Comment: @RajanRaj: No.  I think you should define `status` or `delivery_id` differently, so that the desired ordering need not sort them in opposing directions.

Comment: @eggyal : How to define status or delivery_id differently?

Comment: @RajanRaj: For example, instead of using `status=0` to mean whatever you have defined it to mean, use `status=2`.

Comment: can i have full SQL QUERY?

Comment: @RajanRaj: It has nothing to do with SQL.  It's purely semantical.  *You* have redefine what *you* mean by the values held in the columns.

Comment: @eggyal: Sorry again. I didn't understand your solution. Referring to SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 ASC;  what mean by key_part1?

Comment: @RajanRaj: No, that's not "my solution".  That's a quote from the manual explaining *why* an index cannot be used to fulfil the `ORDER BY` (and therefore why a slow `filesort` must be used instead).